# aws-s3 bucket lists the keys in a hierarchy format

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to download keys from an s3 bucket hosted on aws. The keys are nothing but some .csv files. But these files are stored in subdirectories inside the s3 bucket. When I try to list for a specific file name using s3_client.list_objects-v2(Bucket_name) method, I am returned with the full hierarchy of the keys and the folders in which they are present inside the s3 bucket. Like,
for bucket, bucket_1

```
file_name='my_file.csv'
resp=s2_client_conn.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucket_1')
for obj in resp['Contents']:
   if file_name in obj['Key']:
        print(obj['Key'])
```

the output is:

```
sub_dir_1/sub_dir_2/my_csv_file.csv
```

Why it doesn't print the file_name alone? Is the key name points to the whole directory structure for s3 buckets in which the files are present or something else is missing here?

Comment: I guess you are using boto3,  In boto you can't just list files as linux. It'll return all of the files, you can restrict it via Delimiter='/'. Im not an expert in python, im sure that there is a way that we can filter it only CSV files.

Comment: Yes, I've tried limiting the keys using keyname.rindex('/') and it prints out the .csv file names. But, if I'll go for downloading those, it still takes the whole directory structure and creates the sub-folders accordingly in the local server path. Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 4):

Why it doesn't print the file_name alone? It's because that *is* the filename.

Amazon S3 is a **flat object storage service**. It does *not* support folders/directories.

However, it does allow `/` characters in Keys ('filenames'). There are also various calls that can treat the `/` characters as delimiters for the purpose of listing 'sub-directories' (that really don't exist).

For example, you could do this with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 mb my-bucket

aws s3 cp foo s3://my-bucket/folder1/folder2/foo
```

When you go to list the bucket, it will *act* as though *folder1* and *folder2* exist. It also looks like the folders were created, but they weren't. They are merely provided to act like traditional hierarchical directories.

You could then issue this command:

```
aws s3 rm s3://my-bucket/folder1/folder2/foo
```

The `foo` file will be deleted *and the folders will disappear too!* This is because they never existed.

**Hence, the answer to your question:** The Key (filename) is the full path of the object because paths don't actually exist. It's just a name.

If you wish to 'avoid' it, you will need to manipulate the strings. This can be done quite easily in Python, eg:

```
print(obj['Key'].rsplit('/', 1)[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it, the path name is not the structure but just the name of the file. I've tried avoiding the '/' by key_name.rindex('/') and then listing the rest of the part. When I go for downloading those keys on my local directory, the folders are getting created as well along with the .csv files present..

Comment: If you are using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), it will create the directory structure for you. If you are using boto3 to download the files, you have completed control over the location and filename where the file will be saved.

Comment: Okay, that was the answer I was looking for. I've been using aws cli to download the files. I should try with boto3 methods and it should work. thanks again..